# How do I get rid of this little green box on my HTML/CSS page

Tags: html, css

http://pastebin.com/De29tEAg This is my HTML

http://pastebin.com/88BxpnSM This is my CSS

I just started coding yesterday, so bear with me

I decided to create a button (since it's all I can pretty much do), and underneath it, there's this little green box, that is also part of the link. What is it, and how do I get rid of it?[image]

Comment: That'll be the period you have in your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete that full stop/dot/period immediately after the `img` and before the closing `a` tag.

I.e.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://imgur.com/ukmXAgG.gif /">.</a>
```

Should be

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://imgur.com/ukmXAgG.gif /"></a>
```

Comment: This information has already been provided as a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @mark. It does provide an answer to the question. The question was that trivial.

Comment: The code makes the difference, @MartinSmith